# Add padding without moving the element

Tags: html, css, hover, padding

When I hover on an padded element it moves a bit how can I make it stable

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="nav-ul">
    <li ><a href="#" class="nav-item">Profile</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#" class="nav-item">Home</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#" class="nav-item">Friends</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#" class="nav-item">Notifications</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And this is the css code

```css
nav ul li {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-left: 40px;

}
.nav-item{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-item:hover {
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: the answers provided below already answer the question exactly, What you mean exactly when you say *i want the background color to be bigger than the element but it fits it*

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `padding: 5px;` from your css:

```css
.nav-item {
  padding: 5px;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="nav-ul">
    <li ><a href="#" class="nav-item">Profile</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#" class="nav-item">Home</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#" class="nav-item">Friends</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#" class="nav-item">Notifications</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: the background color will fits the content how can i make it bigger

Comment: @S.alhaider You will need for that to add padding but not on the `:hover` element ;) I updated my answer

Comment: i actually transform it to inline-block

Comment: @S.alhaider What do you mean by that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding to it before without hover

```css
.nav-item {
  padding: 5px;
}
.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="nav-ul">
    <li ><a href="#" class="nav-item">Profile</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#" class="nav-item">Home</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#" class="nav-item">Friends</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#" class="nav-item">Notifications</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: i tried it didn't work i want the background color to be bigger than the element but it fits it

Comment: i actually transform it to inline-block

Comment: @AmrSalama Well what's the difference with my answer ?

Comment: @johannchopin No difference, we answered with the same answer at the same time !

Comment: guys chill up it works both of your answers but in my code it's inline-block not as a list so when i hover on an element it moves a bit

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys i figure it out you just need to add padding to both of them

```css
.nav-item{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
.nav-item:hover {
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    padding: 5px;
}
```